# How to blacklist common passwords on UNIX systems?

Tags: password

If we have a file on a server (Linux, AIX, etc) that contains the common passwords, how can we filter passwords based on this?

Comment: http://www.linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/sag-pam_cracklib.html

Comment: The module quoted by @roaima will add some security layers to your passwords, preventing the most common mistakes made by users on password creation, but as far as i know, there isn't a PAM module to index passwords in plaintext(or password hashes) and block them.

Comment: Well, improving my last comment, on Ubuntu for example you have a file called `/usr/share/dict/cracklib-small`. Maybe is just add a bunch of words you think may create a vector of attack...

Comment: Cracklib provides for a reference to a cracklib dictionary. But as I haven't used that particular functionality I don't think my suggestion is worth being an Answer.

Answer (score 2):

`pam_cracklib` provides the option 'dictpath'. pam_cracklib comes with a basic word list located at `/usr/share/dict/cracklib-small`. You can also use other, larger word list instead of the one provided.

Comment: From which PAM version is this available?